# How can I use gradient descent on the dual form of the linear SVM problem?

Tags: svm, gradient-descent, mathematical-statistics

I understand that this is the dual form of the linear SVM problem (with a hard margin):

$J(\mathbf{\alpha}) = \dfrac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m}{
  \sum\limits_{j=1}^{m}{
  \alpha_i \alpha_j y_i y_j {\mathbf{x}_i}^t\cdot\mathbf{x}_j
  }
} \quad - \quad \sum\limits_{i=1}^{m}{\alpha_i}\\
\text{with}\quad \alpha^{(i)} \ge 0 \quad \text{for }i = 1, 2, \cdots, m$

I'm wondering how to solve it using (sub)gradient descent? Perhaps I should remove the constraints first?

$J_{\text{extended}}(\mathbf{\alpha}) = \dfrac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m}{
  \sum\limits_{j=1}^{m}{
  \max(0, \alpha_i) \max(0, \alpha_j) y_i y_j {\mathbf{x}_i}^t\cdot\mathbf{x}_j
  }
} \quad - \quad \sum\limits_{i=1}^{m}{\alpha_i}$

Then I can compute the partial subderivatives:

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \alpha_k}J_{\text{extended}}(\mathbf{\alpha}) = \begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m}\alpha_iy_iy_k{\mathbf{x}_i}^t\cdot\mathbf{x}_k - 1
& \text{ if } \alpha_k \ge 0\\
-1 & if \alpha_k < 0
\end{cases}$

But this does not seem right as the $\alpha_i$ may end up negative. What is the correct approach for this?

Comment: The correct approach is to use a QP solver.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @GeneralAbrial. I'm mostly trying to get a deeper understanding of SVMs.  Also, using Scikit-Learn's SGDClassifier with the hinge loss makes it possible to build an online version of the linear SVM classifier. I'm looking for something similar for kernelized SVMs.  Is it possible?

Comment: @MiniQuark It's not